# Triggering upstream project builds before downstream project

Tags: build, continuous-integration, triggers, hudson

I have the following project layout:

- WAR Project A

  - Upstream Projects

    - Dependency B
    - Dependency C
    - Dependency D

I'm looking to setup A so that every time I want to trigger a build, it will first build B, C, and D.  If either builds for B, C, or D fail then A's build should fail as well.

It seems like a common build case, but I'm not sure how to accomplish it.  There are the following options but they don't seem to have the right relationship:

- Build Triggers - Build after other projects are built

  - Will build the current project after some upstream projects, but I need to control the build from this project since I'm doing a WAR deployment.  I just want to always build dependencies first.
- Post-build Actions - Build other projects

  - Will build projects after this one, but that's backwards for what I want to do.

Is there a build configuration in Hudson (or through a plugin) that will work for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This came up on the Hudson mailing list very recently.  There is no direct support for this type of build configuration in Hudson.

See this thread:
http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/On-demand-build-dependency-handling-simple-2-job-build-td624395.html

You could use the Join plugin to create a 'build+deploy' job.  It would have B,C and D as downstream projects, and then 'A' would become the join target.

Thus B C and D would need to complete successfully.  If so, then the plain 'deploy' job of A would be launched.  If there were any error, A would not launch.   This is effectively the same as what you are asking for.

You can read about the join plugin here:
http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Join+Plugin

Comment: Thanks for this post reference which was very thorough.  For my builds, which use maven2, it will be enough for me to scm-poll on the dependency jobs (B,C, and D from original question), publish to the maven2 repo, and run project A's build whenever I want.

Thanks again.  The posters were right, you don't really need this type of setup, if you can rely on maven/ivy's dependency management.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Apache Ivy project (http://ant.apache.org/ivy/). It handles project dependencies very well, and it has a plugin for Hudson. From the way you describe the problem, I think this solution would work for you.

Comment: I didn't mention in the original post that we already use maven2 for all of our builds.  I was so hung up on purely atomic, grouped, builds that I didn't realize maven2/scm polling will do the trick quite effectively.  Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [Join Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org//display/HUDSON/Join+Plugin), is what you are looking for. so you setup the A-Trigger job who triggers B,C,D and waits until all are finished and than A gets triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar project layout and found after a little bit research the following answeranswer [How do I trigger another job from hudson as a pre-build step?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487104/how-do-i-trigger-another-job-from-hudson-as-a-pre-build-step).
A plugin which will perhaps work in the future is the [PreBuild Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PreBuild+Plugin).