# How do I trigger another job from hudson as a pre-build step?

Tags: hudson, jenkins

How do I trigger another job from hudson as a pre-build step?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

There is a [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin), which enables "Trigger/call builds on other projects" in "Add build step" menu.

Comment: THANK YOU! This is the option I was looking for but is not explicitly mentioned on the plugin's page.

Comment: The docs do mention "usage as a build step", although you need to realize this is what you need, which isn't immediately obvious, certainly not from the plugin name.

Comment: Just an addition that "Trigger/Call build on other project" section should be first and then use other containers like "Execute windows batch command"

Answer (score 10):

You can use the plugin at http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Join+Plugin

Basically you create 3 jobs:

A = your prebuild ste

B = your main job

C = your trigger.

You 'build' C. It calls A, and once A is successful, it calls B. The plugin page gives you more information. The good thing about this plugin is that you can have any number of pre-build jobs.

We actually have a set of 5 pre-build jobs before our main is run.

================================================

If you don't want to try that:

If you are using Linux, you can do the following from within your "shell" script:

```
wget http://yourserver/hudson/job/MyJob/build?delay=0sec
```

This will trigger the job. The bad part about this is that it will not wait for the job to finish.

Comment: Thanks Sagar!! This "bad part" is exactly what I was looking for. But how this Rest API deals with authentication? Because my Jenkins is configure to request login before any action.

Comment: @NaderA.Jabbar The Jenkins ReST API actually supports authentication with Authentication tokens. You could use a per-job token, or your own authentication API token, from scripts. Check out the URL `http://yourserver/hudson/job/MyJob/api` for more information for calling builds using the API. Also, under "Perform a build", there are two links. Check the one for calling a build with parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I know how to answer to your question:
This is the plug-in that you need:

[PreBuild](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PreBuild+Plugin)

It is not widely famous, but it does what you want.

It basically runs a Build before your chosen one. For example: You want A to run before B. 
You click on "run B" it will execute A before running B.

Pro: 
-> Very versatile
-> Easy to use

Cons:
-> No support / Option in case the pre-build fails (e.g. do not build if pre-build fails)
-> The development seems not being that active at all.

Here you can see how it looks like
[image]

**EDIT**

This answer is back from '12, I know you are down-voting it, but back then this was a reliable solution, now I am sure there are other plug-ins that do the job.

Comment: you can use the old version of Jenkins that supports that

Comment: This was written a year ago, of course is not a lively suggestion, but it's a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and I found a way to do:

I am using jenkins version jenkins-1.452-1.1.

Say I have job A and B, and Job A is depending on job B. When building job B, I want A triggered automatically, and B is blocked until A build successfully.

When define build configuration in build section, I add 'trigger build on other projects'. then fill the form.

Comment: I'm having same thing to do in my project,i'm using the Jenkins ver. 1.479, I enable following in job configuration "Build Triggers->Build after other projects are built", but this is not work for me (not execute the the dependent project also i want to know how to pass parameters to depended project)