# Run a task before svn check-out

Tags: hudson, jenkins

I would like to run a task (stop a running vm machine) before Jenkins starts the check-out.

The reason is: VM blocks access to some files I have to update via subversion.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two plugins for controlling virtual machines, depending on whether you are using VirtualBox or VMWare.

I'm quite sure you can configure the pre-build step to be "Suspend" as shown in the images, at least for VMWare.

- [VMware Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/VMware+plugin)
- [VirtualBox Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/VirtualBox+Plugin)

Comment: Thank you! This would work quite well, however I use vmware workstation and the plugin is vmware server only).

Comment: I see. Can you switch over to VirtualBox? Also, what is the purpose of this virtual machine in the environment? How does it block access to files?

Answer (score 0):

Edit your project and set:
 Configure M2 Extra Build Steps --> Execute shell --> Type in whatever you'd like to do. For example:

```
# Wipe the local repository before each build.
rm -rf $WORKSPACE/.repository
```

Comment: Is the M2 function for maven project types only? I have a "free style" project (msbuild, bat + ant) and I don't see that option.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [How do I trigger another job from hudson as a pre-build step?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487104/). I think this has been asked before there.