# How to build a maven project with a specific library?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I've a web-maven project 'A' that depends of a maven project 'B'. I'm using Jenkins to deploy. Before project 'A' deploy process, there is a pre-build parameter that builds the project 'B' and then proceeds with compilation. I'd need to indicate that the project 'A' will use the newly-compiled B.jar instead wich is defined on its pom.xml.

I saw this link [How do I trigger another job from hudson as a pre-build step?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487104/how-do-i-trigger-another-job-from-hudson-as-a-pre-build-step?answertab=active#tab-top), but I don't know how indicates the newly jar.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you using SNAPSHOT versioning? If I understand your question correctly, I am pretty sure SNAPSHOT versioning is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: ok, maybe that's it! But as I proceed to automatically upload the jar project B to Maven repository so that way the "Project A" can use it?

Comment: I'm not sure of your exact needs or setup, but technically, if A and B are building on the same Jenkins server, they will be using the same local Maven Repo. Therefore, as long as you are running the `install` goal on B's build, it will be available to A

Comment: @rmlan, your answer was my solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy, but not guaranteed way is to force dependency updates (-U).

1. Project A pre builds causes B to build
2. B deploys B.jar to repository
3. A maven's build starts, check dependencies (-U), finds the most recent B which is the one you just built

A variation is to use a specific local repository shared between A and B jobs (in the advanced maven config in Jenkins), but that can be annoying if you want the jobs to execute on different slaves.

The more complex, but safer approach I'd recommend is to create a reactor project (i.e. a maven project that has A and B as modules), and build that. It can be tricky to set up if you're dealing with different repositories, but once that's done since A and B are executed in the same reactor you're guaranteed A will use the B that was just built.

Comment: correct explanation, but may have missed the key-word "snapshot", mentioned in the first comment, that made me find the best solution. I searched the term and found some tutorials that helped me. Tks for explanation anyway. Like this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_snapshots.htm

Comment: I was assuming snapshots. The problem with snapshots is that you're going to get either the latest deployed snapshot or a recently cached one (if no -U - note the 'on a daily basis' in the link). Which might or might not be the one you just built if you have more than one system deploying artifacts (think large build cluster with slaves).