# Build some other project when SCM changes before building current project in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, build

I have three Maven projects in Jenkins. Two of them are related to the other one; it means proceeding in projects `A` and/or `B` requires proceeding in project `C`. So whenever project `A` and/or project `B` are going to build, I should build project `C` beforehand. What I want to do is this:

```
If SCM of A has changed Then
    Build C
    Build A
Else If SCM of B has changed Then
    Build C
    Build B
```

Now I want to know how to tell Jenkins to perform this with its options and plugins. If there are none, any help to write a script for performing this task would be really appreciated too!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487104/how-do-i-trigger-another-job-from-hudson-as-a-pre-build-step may help you. There is a Plugin mentioned there called PreBuild: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PreBuild+Plugin

Comment: @S.Spieker that was the solution. Could you please post it as an answer, so I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How do I trigger another job from hudson as a pre-build step?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487104/how-do-i-trigger-another-job-from-hudson-as-a-pre-build-step?lq=1) may help you.

There is a Plugin mentioned there called PreBuild: 
http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PreBuild+Plugin