# Proper way to trigger dependent job execution on Hudson

Tags: java, build, hudson, build-process

I have job A that is building after developers commit code (SCM change). I also have job B that should be run once a day (by cron) and it should use the artifact that results from execution of build A.

Is it possible to configure Hudson job B to run on cron and before it really executes it should trigger execution of job A?

Job A shouldn't know anything about job B.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848764/triggering-upstream-project-builds-before-downstream-project)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a better way to do what you want.  Have Job A mark the files that Job B wants as Artifacts (preserves them between builds).  Then have Job B on it's cron schedule and when it runs, it uses the [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) to retrieve the required files from Job A.  Then Job B can do it's build operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a maven project (which is also a good way to pass artifacts from one build to another), the M2-extra-steps jenkins plugin (now deprecated and integrated into the M2 plugin I think) allows you to do that:

As a pre-build step, add 'build another project', check 'lock until build is done' and that should do what you need.

If you do have a freestyle project - I'm not sure. If the equivalent does not exist you might be able to come up with something based on locks and latches.

All that said, why do you want to rebuild A before B if it hasn't changed since the last SCM commit?